# Collapsing bootstrap navbar does not drop down when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I used bootstrap to create a collapsible navbar when my HTML page was resized past a certain smaller browser width. It worked before I "converted" my website to a React web application. The navbar still collapses to a hamburger button, but the drop down menu no longer works. I read several posts saying that I need to import:

```
import "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";
```

However, when I do this, the page does not load in Chrome at all and the inspector gives these errors which I don't understand. If I comment these import statements out, the page loads fine but the navbar doesn't work as described above. Anyone have any thoughts?

[image: Chrome error]

my JS file code:

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import { Link, IndexLink } from 'react-router';
import LoadingDots from './LoadingDots';
import "../../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js";
import "../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js";

const Header = ({loading}) => {

return (
<nav className="navbar navbar-inverse" id="my-navbar">
  <div className="container ">
    <div className="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" className="navbar-left"><img className="img-responsive navLogo" alt="logo" src={require('../../images/colorMatchLogo75px.jpg')}></img></a>
    </div>
    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/adoptpet">Adopt A Pet</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/findhome">Find A Home For Your Pet</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/contactvet">Contact Veterinarian</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><Link to="/login">Login/Register</Link></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>    
);
};

Header.propTypes = {
  loading: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: When Bootstrap fails to load, as of your log, I would expect _nothing_ to work as announced.

Comment: [HTTP 403](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) means "forbidden", BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this code in your webpack file. This should resolve your Bootstrap Javascript error.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: "jquery",
  jquery: "jquery",
  "window.jQuery": "jquery",
  jQuery:"jquery"
})
```

Now install bootstrap-sass using `npm install bootstrap-sass --save` and import it in ./lib/main.js like this.

```
import bootstrap from '../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js'
import bootstrapmin from '../../../node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js'
```

Now in your routes file where your whole app is rendering import your ./lib/main.js like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import javascript from './lib/main.js

render(
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path='/dashboard' component={App}></Route>
  </Router>, document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Comment: Thanks Shivani, I tried as you suggested. I added the line in my webpack file (copied and pasted it) and added the bootstrap.min.js to my index.js and my my main (called App.js). When I import the bootstrap.min.js into the 2 files, it prevents my site from rendering at all, similar to my original problem. Not sure if I did something wrong.

Comment: Hi @gig6 , i have updated my answer in more detail. Can you please try this if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Shivani! I did the npm install bootstrap-sass --save, but I could not find ./lib/main.js, so that step was not completed. However, I pressed Ctrl + C (on Windows) to terminate the batch job and restarted with npm start. Now it works! I experimented by commenting out certain lines to determine which were necessary. 1)  import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.css in my index.js file. 2) the mod in my webpack file that you listed above. Not sure if the npm install bootstrap-sass --save had an impact but it didn't hurt! Then restart the terminal. Hope this helps others too!